# python len(line) is not the same as the corresponding value

Tags: python

So there is this dataset which I want to format.
In this following code, if I change the argument (len(line)-3)/5 to 43, which is the corresponding value, it will give me IndexError: list index out of range.

Code below works though, which confuses me. Why is that? Does anybody have an idea?

```
for name in filenames:
    # your code here
    f_in = open(name,'r')
    reader_in = csv.reader(f_in, delimiter=',') 
    out_name = "updated_"+name
    f_out = open(out_name,'w')
    writer_out = csv.writer(f_out, delimiter=',')

    for line in reader_in:
        x = 0
        a = line[0]
        b = line[1]
        c = line[2]

        for i in range(3,(len(line)-3)/5):
            row = [a,b,c,line[x+3],line[x+4],line[x+5],line[x+6],line[x+7]]
            writer_out.writerow(row)
            x+=5

    f_in.close()
    f_out.close()
```

Comment: Python begins counting at zero.  A list of length 10 has indices 0 through 9.

Comment: Are you sure `(len(line)-3)/5 == 43` and that `len(line)` is fixed? If `(len(line)-3)/5 == 43` is _always_ `True` and `len(line)` is fixed, then one cannot succeed while the other fails, but something tells me that's not actually the case. Note that the `/ 5` bit (assuming this is Python 2 without `from __future__ import division`) means that you could have stuff rounding correctly for some line lengths, and not for others, due to the way `/` does C-style truncating division when used with integers on Python 2.